# Java ArrayList clear() function

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Let's say I have a `ArrayList<String> data;`

I'm adding some data into this Array, using `data.add()` function.
Let's say I've added 10 Strings into this array. The size of the array is 10 now.

How do i destroy all elements in the array? The `data.clear()` function just set's all 10 elements to null. So when I try to add another element, it just get's on the 11 position. I want just to start it over from 0;

I can use a for loop to replace all the data, but I really think there is a way just to empty the `ArrayList`. Is it?

Comment: Do you have a smaller test-case that you can show is broken?

Comment: `data.clear()` is supposed to remove everything for you, but keep the array. [The size goes back to zero, though](http://ideone.com/DiCpYK), so you wouldn't start at 11, you'll start at `0`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your assumptions don't seem to be right. After a `clear()`, the newly added data start from index 0.

Comment: I've just managed to research my code. You're trully right. I just had an error in my other method, that was filling out my previous data. I'll read the documentation first, before asking stupid question from now.

Answer (score 26):

If you in any doubt, have a look at JDK source code

`ArrayList.clear()` source code:

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // Let gc do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}
```

You will see that `size` is set to 0 so you start from 0 position.

Please note that when adding elements to `ArrayList`, the backend array is extended (i.e. array data is copied to bigger array if needed) in order to be able to add new items. When performing `ArrayList.clear()` you only remove references to array elements and sets `size` to 0, however, **`capacity`** stays as it was.

Answer (score 10):

ArrayList.clear(From [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29)):

Removes all of the elements from this list. The list will be empty after this call returns

Answer (score 9):

After `data.clear()` it will definitely start again from the zero index.

Answer (score 8):

`data.removeAll(data);` will do the work, I think.

Comment: Both this and `clear()` should do the trick, however `clear()` is bound to be faster. (OT: You just hit 10K!)

Comment: @ninetwozero thanks a lot. I reached 10K now and you are the first person to congrat me. thanks again =)

Answer (score 5):

it's not true  the `clear()` function  clear the Arraylist and start from index 0

Answer (score 3):

Source code of clear shows the reason why the newly added data gets the first position.

```
 public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // Let gc do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
    }
```

clear() is faster than removeAll() by the way, first one is O(n) while the latter is O(n_2)